# How do I install Apigility if I don't have Composer?

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a hosting in shared web server. I don't have [Composer](https://github.com/composer/composer) there. How can I make it run, the [Apigility](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-apigility-skeleton)?

Edit: I don't have administrative right there.

Answer (score 3):

1) You can install the ZF2 skeleton application first using git submodules. Take a look at the install section of the ZF2 skeleton application.

2) You can take a look at all the dependencies for Apigility in the composer.json file. https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-apigility/blob/master/composer.json you can start installing each dependencies using git submodules in to your vendor directory and activate them in the application.config.php file.

3) launch the php built in webserver ( $ php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public/ public/index.php )

It is recommended to use php 5.4.* or later to use apigility.

I wrote a blog post showing how to include the apigility in to your exiting zf2 project (I am using the composer there), see if that helps.

http://www.ttiaf.com/2013/10/install-apigility-in-to-your-existing.html

Answer (score 1):

step1;

download from [Github](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-apigility-admin)

then just go to your project_root_folder/config/development.config.php

create a new php file with the path shown above.

```
<?php

    return array(
    // Development time modules
    'modules' => array(
        'ZFTool',
        'ZF\Apigility\Admin',
        'ZF\Apigility\Example',
    ),
    // development time configuration globbing
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'config_glob_paths' => array('config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}-development.php')
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Composer on the machine you are using for uploading to your shared host.
2. Download the dependencies there.
3. Upload the whole directory tree to the server.